# Android Studio module names in red

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I have tried to restart, clean, rebuild and start a new project but problem still persists. The project builds and runs if there are no errors but its hard to find these errors.

Answer (score 0):

In **Android Studi**o go to **Preferences** type **Android SDK**. You should see **Android SDK Location** menu click **Edit** check if any component is missing and click next it will install missing packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

We need to make sure that android studio has the correct path pointing to the android sdk.
Go to tools>android>android sdk manager and check if the path for the android SDK is correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Follow step bellow:

> 1. Tools >> Android >> Sync Project with Gradle Files
> 2. Build >> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

Correct the path for your Android SDK by checking Android Studio Preferences. There might also be missing packages, if you find any, install them. Rebuild your project after following these steps